# Sorting STS_ListItem_Tasks by DueDate in result source in Office 365

Tags: 2013, search, office-365

Since we can't create a new sortable managed property in Office 365 I have mapped ows_DueDate to RefinableDate00.

If I add it to a refiner in the search center it allows me to refine tasks by due date as expected.

But I can't seem to use it as a sorting property when creating a result source.

The (tenant) result source fires the query `ContentClass:STS_ListItem_Tasks AssignedTo:{User.Name}`.

The kicker is that it actually changes the results in some small way when switching between asc and desc, just not correctly.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Tasks are available for users on the task tab, served up by the Task Management Service. Is that an alternative?

Comment: Using the content search webpart on the sites startpage to list the tasks for a user across site collections that are due next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the mapping on a level which covers all tasks, and recrawled all tasks lists, it should work just fine. And all items also need the field set for it to sort properly.

Comment: "And all items also need the field set for it to sort properly" - Thank you! Is this documented anywhere that I missed?

Comment: Well, if the MP is missing a value, it cannot be sorted and will appear below all items with a value. Which might be ok :)